# Excel VBA counter based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba

so I want to make a counter for this excel list

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWO7K.jpg

| Order | Oper./ Act. | Opr. Short text | Act. start | Act. finish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31663320 | 0010 | Generator Hochzeit | 04.11.2020 | 04.11.2020 |
| 31663320 | 0020 | Generator Setup | 04.11.2020 | 04.11.2020 |
| 31663320 | 0030 | Generator Dauertest |  |  |

the idea is to track how many number of generators are on each step (Hochzeit, Setup, Dauertest and Endkontrolle), so it will go like this, if the Timestamps are found on Hochzeit and the Setup is without any timestamps it means that the generator is in Setup now, for Dauertest or Endkontrolle, if the timestamps are found both in Setup and Hochzeit, the generator will be stuck in either Dauertest or Endkontrolle. I came up with this but cant move forward from here.

```
Sub counter180 ()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'Declare Variables
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dom row1 As Long
Dim Row1Count As Long
Dim GenID as Long
Dim Hochzeit As Integer
Dim Setup As Integer
Dim Endkontrolle As Integer
Dim Dauertest As Integer


Setup=0
Hochzeit=0
Endkontrolle=0
Dauertest=0

Set ws1= Worksheets(1)


'For Hochzeit
Row1Count=ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For row1=2 To Row1Count
   GenId= CLng(ws1.Cells(row1,1).Value)
If Cells(row1,4) = "Generator Hochzeit" Then
     If (Cells(row1, 6) = "") Then
     Hochzeit = Hochzeit+1
     End if
     End if
Next row1
MsgBox (Hochzeit)


'For Setup
Row1Count=ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For row1=2 To Row1Count
   GenId= CLng(ws1.Cells(row1,1).Value)
If Cells(row1,4) = "Generator Setup" Then
     If (Cells(row1, 6) = "") Then
     Setup= Setup+1
     End if
     End if
Next row1
MsgBox (Setup)

'For Endkontrolle
Row1Count=ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For row1=2 To Row1Count
   GenId= CLng(ws1.Cells(row1,1).Value)
If Cells(row1,4) = "Generator Endkontrolle" Then
     If (Cells(row1, 6) = "") Then
     Endkontrolle= Endkontrolle+1
     End if
     End if
Next row1
MsgBox (Endkontrolle)



'For Dauertest
Row1Count=ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For row1=2 To Row1Count
   GenId= CLng(ws1.Cells(row1,1).Value)
If Cells(row1,4) = "Generator Dauertest" Then
     If (Cells(row1, 6) = "") Then
     Dauertest= Dauertest+1
     End if
     End if
Next row1
MsgBox (Dauertest)


Exit Sub

ErrorHandler: 

MsgBox ("An error occured")

End Sub
```

So basically this code just counted the number of cells with a timestamp that is empty, but I dont want that, I want to count it only if the step before it is timestamped.

Comment: You say "if timestamps are found in both hochzeit and setup, the generator is in either dauertest or endkontrolle". Which one is it and how can you tell? Also please update your question so that your data shows as an actual table instead of just a screenshot so we can copy it and test it more easily. You can use this: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: @andrewb That is what makes it very complicated for me as well, my supervisor told me that Endkontrolle and Dauertest doesn't have any specific order, whatever test is available we can use. Therefore I cannot use same conditions for these two as the conditions for Setup for example since Setup is always the second test after Hochzeit (which is the first one). p.s: table added

Answer (score 0):

Alright I made this. Let me know if it works and if you need any clarification. I put some comments in the code as well.

Also please note that this assumes that the number of rows in your data is divisible by 4 and that it is always ordered like you show in your example.

```vb
Sub dauerendhochsetup()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    
    'replace "data" with whatever your table is called. Or just put in a range
    arr = Range("data")
    
    Dim stampCol As Integer

    'replace the 2 with the index of the column the stamps are in
    stampCol = 2
    
    'I shortened the counter variables to single letters
    Dim h As Long, s As Long, d As Long, e As Long
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) Step 4
        Dim hasH As Boolean, hasS As Boolean, hasD As Boolean, hasE As Boolean
        If arr(i, stampCol) <> vbNullString Then hasH = True Else hasH = False
        If arr(i + 1, stampCol) <> vbNullString Then hasS = True Else hasS = False
        If arr(i + 2, stampCol) <> vbNullString Then hasD = True Else hasD = False
        If arr(i + 3, stampCol) <> vbNullString Then hasE = True Else hasE = False
        
        'not sure if this logic is what you want, please test thoroughly
        If Not hasH Then h = h + 1
        If hasH And Not hasS Then s = s + 1
        If hasH And hasS And hasD And Not hasE Then e = e + 1
        If hasH And hasS And hasE And Not hasD Then d = d + 1
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print h
    Debug.Print s
    Debug.Print d
    Debug.Print e
End Sub
```

Tested on this table:

| Opr. short text | Act. start | Act. finish |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Generator Hochzeit | 04.11.2022 | 04.11.2022 |
| Generator Setup | 04.11.2022 | 04.11.2022 |
| Generator Dauertest | 04.11.2022 | 04.11.2022 |
| Generator Endkontrolle |  |  |
| Generator Hochzeit | 14.11.2022 | 14.11.2022 |
| Generator Setup |  |  |
| Generator Dauertest |  |  |
| Generator Endkontrolle |  |  |
| Generator Hochzeit | 21.11.2022 | 21.11.2022 |
| Generator Setup |  |  |
| Generator Dauertest |  |  |
| Generator Endkontrolle |  |  |
| Generator Hochzeit | 09.01.2023 | 09.01.2023 |
| Generator Setup |  |  |
| Generator Dauertest |  |  |
| Generator Endkontrolle |  |  |

Output:

[image]